# How to build a 'panel' in iPhone dev (with picture)?

Tags: iphone, toolbar, uitoolbar

I need a toolbar like "panel" that could contain text fields and buttons, just like a toolbar you can define its width and height and its position. And you can put the elements you want into the "toolbar".

Like the following:

[alt text http://s3.amazonaws.com/entp-tender-production/assets/b6e1e6b369c17143626311c3872bfec079e988b5/toolbar1.png?AWSAccessKeyId=1AJ9W2TX1B2Z7C2KYB82&Expires=1255600931&Signature=sE8Zi%2B3mKWcXDG%2F14rYTVb58fI0%3D](http://s3.amazonaws.com/entp-tender-production/assets/b6e1e6b369c17143626311c3872bfec079e988b5/toolbar1.png?AWSAccessKeyId=1AJ9W2TX1B2Z7C2KYB82&Expires=1255600931&Signature=sE8Zi%2B3mKWcXDG%2F14rYTVb58fI0%3D)

[alt text http://s3.amazonaws.com/entp-tender-production/assets/f566c7ac698bbc87fed7d27e88355b789bec89c6/toolbar2.png?AWSAccessKeyId=1AJ9W2TX1B2Z7C2KYB82&Expires=1255601035&Signature=gn2lf08YMhW%2FTi6MeamxWeXu4cQ%3D](http://s3.amazonaws.com/entp-tender-production/assets/f566c7ac698bbc87fed7d27e88355b789bec89c6/toolbar2.png?AWSAccessKeyId=1AJ9W2TX1B2Z7C2KYB82&Expires=1255601035&Signature=gn2lf08YMhW%2FTi6MeamxWeXu4cQ%3D)

Any clues?

Comment: The images you added have either timed out or are only available with authentication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I understand.  Can you not take a plain `UIView` and put text fields and buttons in it, with whatever height and width, and then `addSubview` it when you need to see it and `removeFromSuperview` when you are done?

Comment: I tried, but how to make it look like a "toolbar", I mean the background?

Comment: And I don't want the elements in it to move (if you slide on the view, the elements will move). Just make it a real "panel"

Comment: Do you have a picture of what you are trying to do?  The elements in a UIView don't move around unless you resize the view, and even then you can lock them down.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the toolbar and add add subViews to it. You can layer UIViews and UIButtons as text.